# An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator

Tags: entities, ajax

I have a taxonomy list of 'make' of vehicle say 'Toyota'. The second list would be models of the make selected make - 'Corolla', 'Hilux', 'Land Cruiser' etc. I'm using the http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/244/create-a-custom-content-entity-on-drupal-8-full. I have tried different options on the vehicleForm.php. I can't get past this error when I click to save the vehicle entity. if I comment "'#validated' => TRUE," the error changes to "Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase::massageFormValues() must be of the type array, string given...". I have googled these 2 errors without success. Please help. So far here is my code:

```
namespace Drupal\vehicle\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm;
/**
 * VehicleForm.
 */
class VehicleForm extends ContentEntityForm {
//  class VehicleForm extends FormBase {
  /**
   * The term Storage.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\taxonomy\TermStorageInterface
   */
  protected $termStorage;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity) {
    $this->termStorage = $entity->getStorage('taxonomy_term');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    // Instantiates this form class.
    return new static(
    // Load the service required to construct this class.
    $container->get('entity_type.manager')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'vehicle_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $params = NULL) {

    $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
    $entity = $this->entity;

    $terms = $this->termStorage->loadTree('make', 0, NULL, TRUE);
    $options = [];
    if ($terms) {
      foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $options[$term->getName()] = $term->getName();
      }
    }
    $form['make'] = array(
      '#type'    => 'select',
      '#title'   => $this->t('make'),
      '#options' => $options,
      '#ajax'    => array(
        'callback' => [$this, 'selectModelsAjax'],
        'wrapper'  => 'model_wrapper',
      ),
    );

    $form['model'] = array(
      '#type'      => 'select',
      '#title'     => $this->t('Model'),
      '#options'   => ['_none' => $this->t('- Select a make first -')],
      '#prefix'    => '<div id="model_wrapper">',
      '#suffix'    => '</div>',
//      '#validated' => TRUE,
    );


    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function save(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $status = parent::save($form, $form_state);
    //dpm($status);
    $entity = $this->entity;
    if ($status == SAVED_UPDATED) {
      drupal_set_message($this->t('The contact %feed has been updated.', ['%feed' => $entity->toLink()->toString()]));
    } else {
      drupal_set_message($this->t('The contact %feed has been added.', ['%feed' => $entity->toLink()->toString()]));
    }

    $form_state->setRedirectUrl($this->entity->toUrl('collection'));
    return $status;
  }


  /**
   * Called via Ajax to populate the Model field according make.
   *
   * @param array $form
   *   An associative array containing the structure of the form.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   The current state of the form.
   *
   * @return array
   *   The form model field structure.
   */
  public function selectModelsAjax(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $options = [];

    $vocabulary = 'title';
    switch ($form_state->getValue('make')) {
      case 'Benz':
        $vocabulary = 'benz';
        break;
      case 'BMW':
        $vocabulary = 'bmw';
        break;
      case 'Toyota':
        $vocabulary = 'toyota';
        break;
    }

    $models = $this->termStorage->loadTree($vocabulary, 0, NULL, TRUE);
    if ($models) {
      foreach ($models as $model) {
        $options[$model->id()] = $model->getName();
      }
    }
    $form['model']['#options'] = $options;

    return $form['model'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make changes to the $form array in ajax callback functions, as the form has already been cached. When Drupal later compares the submitted values to the cache, they don't exist, and you see the error you are seeing.

All changes to the form need to be made in the form definition (or a _form_alter() hook). Use values in the form state to determine if you are in an ajax submit or the initial form build.

Comment: Thanks Jaypan, Not sure if I understood your instructions. I have removed all code in my callback function 'selectModelsAjax' except 'return $form['model'];' and now havethe following code between the 'make' and 'model'. $vocabulary = $form_state->getValue('make');
$terms = $this->termStorage->loadTree($vocabulary, 0, NULL, TRUE);
if ($terms) {
   foreach ($terms as $term) {
       $options1[$term->getName()] = $term->getName();
   }
} and now getting the error: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase::massageFormValues() must be of the type array, string given? Any ideas?